# Для чего нужны дженерик параметры в объявлении делегата, если все типы входных и выходных параметров строго определены?

Tags: c#, делегаты

Такой вопрос, для чего в объявлении делегата в данном примере нужны дженерик параметры <Т1, Т2> если их нет в конъюнктуре метода на который ссылается делегат, то есть все входные и выходные параметры определены конкретным типом данных, что определяют Т1 и Т2? (без них ошибка). Делегат TryGet ссылается на метод AskUser. Код  с портала Ulearn.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication14
{
delegate bool TryGet <T1, T2> (string question, Action<string> action, out int age);

class Program 
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
        Run(AskUser, Console.WriteLine);
    }
    static void Run(TryGet <string, int> askUser, Action<string> tellUser)
    {
        int age;
        if (askUser("What is your age?", tellUser, out age))
            tellUser("Age: " + age);
    }

    static bool AskUser(string questionText, Action<string> tellUser, out int age)
    { // метод на который ссылается делегат TryGet
tellUser(questionText);
var answer = Console.ReadLine();
return int.TryParse(answer, out age);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Не надо задавать новые вопросы удаляя при этом старые. Вы так автобан схватите за суммарную отрицательную репутацию.

Comment: ясно извините не знал просто предыдущий вопрос и его код отличается

Comment: Для этих целей у вас есть кнопка редактирования.

Comment: Учту на будующее первый раз пользуюсь порталом+

Comment: _если все типы входных и выходных параметров строго определены_ - ни для чего

Comment: Visual studio с вами не согласен, я бы не стал писать сюда, если бы все было так просто))

Comment: @Bulat, спорим убрав generic параметры из определения ты не убрал их в параметре метода Run и поэтому студия тебе ошибку выдавала?

Comment: Только что попробовал, извиняюсь вы были правы! все дело было именно в этой строке вопрос закрыт.